# Where does read only memory exist in code after compilation

Tags: c, memory

```
char *token = "some random string";
```

When I declare this, I know "some random string" is stored in read-only memory. My question is where will read-only memory be? Will it be in the data section or in bss?

Comment: [C String literals: Where do they go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go)

Answer (score 1):

It will be in the data section, BSS is for non-initialized memory.

If using GNU binutils, you can use [`nm`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm) to list the contents of an executable and see in which sections various symbols reside.